# Отображается неверный title в гугле

Tags: html

Проблема такова: не отображается title в гугле, хотя в яндексе все в порядке.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @kzcool, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы обеспокоены содержанием заголовка или фрагмента, тщательно проверьте, не встречается ли такое содержание на вашем сайте. Если оно действительно появляется на ваших страницах, удалите его, и изменения будут отражены в результатах поиска Google после очередного сканирования вашего сайта.
Если такого содержания на странице нет, попробуйте выполнить поиск заголовка или фрагмента, заключенного в кавычки, на Google.ru. В результатах будут показаны веб-страницы, на которых этот текст используется для ссылки на ваш сайт. Получите консультацию у специалистов Google

Answer (score 0):

В кэше? Возможно гугл не успел перечитать Ваш сайт, после внесения изменений.

Comment: Нет, не в кэше, именно в поиске.
Дело в том, что изменения были месяц назад, т.е. довольно таки большие сроки

Answer (score 0):

Гугл может и сам формировать Title страниц.
Неоднократно сталкивался с этим. ) Может, Заголовок не соответствует содержанию страницы, и поэтому так.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял... Нажмите F12  в GoogleChrome, пройдите в раздел просмотра текста страницы в HTML, поиском или просто найдите `title` и посмотрите - указано ли там что-то.